# Update Postgresql in Ubuntu - pg_upgrade vs pg_upgradecluster

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I would like to switch from postgres 9.6 to version 14 which runs on Ubuntu 21.04. I have a cluster with 3 databases.
I would like to know what is the difference between upgrading with pg_upgrade and pg_upgradecluster? Which one is faster and safer?

Comment: `pg_upgradecluster` is PERL script wrapper(/usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster) over the `pg_upgrade` process. To see what it's options are do `man pg_upgradecluster`. If you have installed using the Ubuntu Postgres process you should probably stick with it i.e use `pg_upgradecluster`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_upgrade` is a tool from Postgresql itself that will operate on a single database (folder).

`pg_upgradecluster` however is a wrapper from your operating system (= Ubuntu) to `pg_upgrade` or `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`. In addition to very conveniently upgrading your database, it will also do some housekeeping like moving the config files to the correct folder in /etc/postgres/ .

So, if you have set up your database by `pg_createcluster` and it is hence listed by `pg_lsclusters`, I'd strongly recommend using `pg_upgradecluster` to upgrade it.

In terms of "**faster vs. safer**", be sure to read about the various options on the [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_upgradecluster.8.html).

If you can take a reliable backup (e.g.  snapshot), you can safely use the `-m upgrade --link` option which will be **fastest** and allow for a very short downtime (depending on database size and resources, but I've recently upgraded a 700GB database in ~25 seconds).

The **safest** option of course is not using `pg_upgrade`, but the default `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` method, which will shut down your original database and copy the data to a new database in a new location (= it will use at approx. twice the space, at least temporarily until you decide to delete the original folder).